# Python Requests Proxy Error

Tags: python, proxy

So when i try to use proxy on python requests , the actual requests send is using my own ip

```
http_proxy  = "https://103.235.21.128:80"

proxyDict = {
              "http"  : http_proxy,
            }

r = requests.get('http://whatismyip.org',proxies=proxyDict)
print r.content
```

Also Tried

```
http_proxy  = "https://103.235.21.128:80"

proxyDict = {
              "https"  : http_proxy,
            }

r = requests.get('http://whatismyip.org',proxies=proxyDict)
print r.content
```

So why the request is using my real ip instead of the proxy i provide

Comment: It's highly unlikely that your proxy uses port 80 for https, and that is probably what's causing the proxy not to work for you. You should check what ports you proxy handles for each protocol (http, https, ftp, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting http on the proxy like this?

```
http_proxy  = "http://103.235.21.128:80"
```

or

```
http_proxy = "http://{}:{}".format('103.235.21.128', 80)
```

If that doesn't work you might have to find an http proxy

If you're requesting data from multiple websites (both http and https) then you'll have to add both to the dictionary:

```
proxyDict = {"http": http_proxy, "https": http_proxy}
```